# Group by Category and Set Threshold in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to group each threshold.

```
group      start           end            Percent    

A          2019-04-01      2019-05-01     21       
A          2019-05-01      2019-06-01      8 
A          2019-07-01      2019-08-01      5        
B          2020-06-01      2020-07-01      7         
B          2020-07-01      2020-08-01      5  
B          2020-09-01      2020-10-01      3
```

For A: If value is greater than 20 - A Too High
If value is less than 6 -  A Too Low

For B: If the value is greater than 6 - B Too High
If the value is less than 1 - B Too Low

```
type      start           end            Percent           Result 

A          2019-04-01      2019-05-01     21                A Too High   
A          2019-05-01      2019-06-01      8                A Ok
A          2019-07-01      2019-08-01      5                A Too Low                 
B          2020-06-01      2020-07-01      7                B Too High                               
B          2020-07-01      2020-08-01      5                B Ok
B          2020-09-01      2020-10-01      3                B Ok
```

This is what I am doing: (I have had some suggestion from a StackOverflow member, but am wanting to expand)

```
df1 = df.groupby('type')

df2= df1['result']=pd.cut(df1.Percent, [-np.inf, 6, 20,np.inf], labels= 
['unacceptablelow','acceptable', 
'unacceptablehigh'])

df3= df2['result']=pd.cut(df2.Percent, [-np.inf, 1, 6,np.inf], labels= 
['unacceptablelow','acceptable', 
'unacceptablehigh'])
```

However, I am not sure how to set each group to these thresholds.
I am actively researching this. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `np.select(condition, choice, alternative)`

```
condition=[(df.group.eq('B')&df.Percent.gt(6))|(df.group.eq('A')&df.Percent.gt(20)),(df.group.eq('B')&df.Percent.lt(1))|(df.group.eq('A')&df.Percent.lt(6))]
    
    
choice=['Too High','Too Low']
    
df['result']=np.select(condition, choice, 'ok')
```

Comment: Hi. Ok let me try . The in between values are just set to: ‘Ok’

Comment: Oh I see. Thank you. Let me try